# splitting a string using the regex but ignore the separators within the quotes and the separators should be dynamic

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following regex expression to split the delimiters in the string but ignoring the separators within the quotes

```
re.split('''[|,](?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)'', data)
```

but the delimiters which i declared manually should be dynamic ,how will i use a variable in the above regex expression instead of specifying the delimiters in the regex expression itself

```
data="\"john\"|\"100032487\"|\"ab|cdef\"|\"ghijkl\""
output = re.split('''[|,](?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)'', data)
```

instead of `[|,]` i should assign these delimiters to a variable and use the variable in the above regex expression

Comment: What is your desired I/O?

Comment: i should be able to send the delimiters through a variable to the above mentioned  regex expression to be splitted

Comment: i'm getting the desired results but the separators i should send as a variable in split function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a regex to parse CSV styled data. The Python [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) library is able to parse that.

For example the following approach:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

data = "\"john\"|\"100032487\"|\"ab|cdef\"|\"ghijkl\""
print(next(csv.reader(StringIO(data), delimiter='|')))
```

would return the data as four items in a list:

```
['john', '100032487', 'ab|cdef', 'ghijkl']
```

As the third item is enclosed in quotes, it normally means that delimiters inside should be ignored. This kind of required logic is why using a regex for this is not recommended.

The `csv.reader()` takes a file object, so as `data` is a string I first use `StringIO()` to make `data` like a file.